# React JS setInterval not working and not resetting my state to 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I want to ask regarding my `setInterval` function. I wanted to do something like a carousel auto scroll for my Quotes component.

Problem: The `setInterval` incremented my `currQuote` state from 0 to 1 and then stops at 1 and did not set back to 0 as coded in the else statement.

SOLVED: Thank you guys. This was a very silly mistake. I didnt add the dependencies for the `useEffect`. No wonder it just run once XD

```
const Quote = () => {
  const [currQuote, setCurrQuote] = useState(0);
  const timerQuote = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    timerQuote.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (currQuote < quoteList.length - 1) {
        setCurrQuote(currQuote + 1);
      } else {
        setCurrQuote(0);
      }
      // console.log(currQuote);
    }, 2000);

    // dispose when unmount
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerQuote.current);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currQuote);
  }, [currQuote]);

return(.......)
```

Comment: Callback function of `setInterval` has a closure over the `currQuote` state; it always sees the value of `currQuote` to be 0. This is why you shouldn't omit the dependencies of the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: ok tq very much. That was a very bad mistake xD. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like Yousaf commented, you need to add the `currQuote` to the dependency array of the `useEffect` like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    timerQuote.current = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(currQuote)
      if (currQuote < quoteList.length - 1) {
        setCurrQuote(currQuote + 1);
      } else {
        setCurrQuote(0);
      }
      // console.log(currQuote);
    }, 2000);

    // dispose when unmount
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerQuote.current);
    };
  }, [currQuote]);
```

Working sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-architecture-rgwgoz?file=/src/App.js